# Array String null

Tags: c++, winapi

Why does my IntForItem1 go over the max lenght of arrayStrings???

```
int TotalItems = 0, IntForItem1 = 0;

struct Item
{
    int Index;
    std::string* stringArray = new std::string[555]; //random value coz it will change in GetItems right?
};

Item item[120];

int AddNewItem(int i, int Index, std::string stringarray[])
{
    item[i].Index = Index;
    item[i].stringArray = stringarray;
    return (i + 1);
}

void GetItems() 
{
    int i = 0;

    std::string * test = new std::string[4]{ "1", "2", "3", "4"};
    i = AddNewItem(i, IntForItem1, test);

    TotalItems = i;
}

int main()
{
    GetItems();

    while (true)
    {
        system("CLS");

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalItems; i++)
            std::cout << item[i].stringArray[item[i].Index].c_str();

        while (true)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 1)
            {
                if (item[0].Index <= 0)
                    item[0].Index = 0;
                else
                    item[0].Index -= 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 1)
            {
                if (item[0].Index >= sizeof(item[0].stringArray))
                    item[0].Index = sizeof(item[0].stringArray);
                else
                    item[0].Index += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you never leave the inner while loop, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: why use a pointer to int as the index? Why not just int? Also, if you want a fixed array, consider `std::array<std::string, 3>`

Comment: This code leaks memory

Comment: You might also look into the `std::vector` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(item[0].stringArray)` in your code is the size of the `string` pointer, not the size of the space you set.

[image: 1]

You can try this.

[image: 2]

In additon, you should pay attention to the size of your array, otherwise you will always right-click the size of the array, can cause array crossing bounds, causing program errors.